# jQuery for setting background color in asp repeater based on changed value of a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a repeater in my asp.net web page that contains a table with rows.
There are several textboxes, dropdowns and other fields in a row.
What I want is that when a value of one of my dropdowns in my repeater row changes, that the whole table row gets a color.
I managed to do this server-side, but I want it client-side.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="InvoerUrenTable" class="InvoerUrenLeftMargin100">    
<asp:Repeater ID="urenRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" ID="itemTemplateRow">
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <td >
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="projectDropDown" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#projectDropDown').change(function () {
              var index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
              $('#urenRepeater tr:nth-child(' + index + ')').addClass("highlight")    
          });
      });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
background-color: #E52718;
}
```

The above script doesn't seems to work.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 06/07/2020**

I found out I was selecting the wrong row id to change the class.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.projDropDown').change(function () {
              var index = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
              $('#body_urenRepeater_itemTemplateRow_' + index).addClass("highlight")    
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Now is the problem that my index is wrong, it marks everytime the first row if I change the value of one of my dropdowns.

Comment: can you add `html generated` code for `asp` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the dropdown is in a repeater - and can therefore potentially be copied multiple times in the final page -, it will either end up with a different ID in the rendered HTML (if asp.net attempts to make the IDs unique in the browser), or you'll end up with multiple dropdowns with the same ID (which is invalid). Either way you've got problems because the jQuery code can't identify the correct one to target.

I suggest using a CSS class as your selector instead. That won't get altered by the asp.net rendering engine, and it also will allow you to target multiple elements with one event handler.

e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="projectDropDown" CssClass="projDropDown" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

and

```
$('.projDropDown').change(function () {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed it to a class, but still no luck in getting it to work.

Comment: "no luck" doesn't give me any useful information with which to help you further. It would be helpful if you use the View Source feature of your browser to examine the finished HTML which is sent by asp.net to the browser. That finished HTML is what jQuery is working with (it doesn't know anything about `<asp:Repeater` or `<asp:Dropdownlist` - that stuff is only used by ASP.NET on the server side to generate the real HTML which then goes to the browser). Show us the HTML which your repeater produces, then we have a better chance of seeing where the jQuery might be going wrong.

Comment: Also, what _exactly_ happens when you run the code? Did you debug the JQuery (e.g. by using your browser's Debugger, or by adding some console logging)? e.g. did you verify whether the "change" event is fired? It would be useful to distinguish whether the event is fired, but it fails to then add the highlight, or whether the event is never fired at all. There are different solutions to those two scenarios. That kind of information, plus the HTML, will allow us to understand the situation more clearly.